# Renaming computer in powershell in a text file and joining domain

Tags: powershell, foreach, rename, powershell-3.0

I am a powershell newbie and I'm trying to develop a small script in powershell to rename computers in a text file and join them in a domain. I know the main steps but I have some difficulties with the details.

First, I'm using powershell 3.0 and I launch the script from a remote server. Since my computers are freshly dematerialised, I only have the ip adress to help me. Fortunatly, we are using static IP so I created a text file with all ip adress in order I want them to be.

The first problem is our name convention is department-local-00 , 01 , 02  and on and on... I'm unable to create a loop with 2 digits... only 1 for the first 9 entries (0, 1, 2, 3 ....). I tried many thing but it just seems cumbersome and doesn't work.

Here's my code so far:

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\blablabla\computer\test.txt"
$room = "b4554"
$b = 0

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
    {
        Write-Host ("department-" + $room + "-" + $b)
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -credential ladmin -ScriptBlock {Rename-Computer -NewName ("logti-" + $classe + "-" + $b) } 
        add-computer -DomainName axiom.ad.ca -Credential AXIOM\dadmin
        Restart-Computer -computername $computer
        $b = $b + 1
        $computer
    }
```

So far... the only things that's been bugging me is I can't add 00 to 09 in my loop and that it seems by using the -credential switch I am sending my domain admin username and password in clear... which is far from ideal.

Anyone have an idea how to clean this up? I'm open to suggestion if anyone have a better idea.

Comment: Are you just looking for `PadLeft`? `$b.PadLeft(2,"0")` = `01`. If that is the case your title was misleading since it looks like you have 2 questions.

Comment: Well there are many items in my question. With padleft, why are you addind = 01 at the end? I am not that good with scripting and I am a total newbie concerning powershell. I also want to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: I was trying to show an example but I could see how that was misleading. If `$b` was 1 then `$b.PadLeft(2,"0")` would return `01` since it was instructed to pad 0's up to 2 characters. If `$b` was 13 it would just return 13

Comment: Oh! Now I understand! I'll give it a try. I'll be back with the results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your strings using the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

```
foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
    {
        Write-Host ("department-{0}-{1:d2}" -f $room, $b)
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -credential ladmin -ScriptBlock {
          Rename-Computer -NewName ("logti-{0}-{1:d2}" -f $args[0], $args[1])
        } -ArgumentList $classe, $b
        add-computer -DomainName axiom.ad.ca -Credential AXIOM\dadmin
        Restart-Computer -computername $computer
        $b++
        $computer
    }
```

Comment: Will try tommorow! If this works, I owe you big time!

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunatly. While when I use write-host, I have the good name, it seems that Rename-Computer doesn't register the -f properly. The output i get in this example is logti--     Any ideas?

Comment: @Axiom The scriptblock doesn't recognize the variables, so you need to pass them as arguments. See updated answer.